# Run more than 1 Azure Devops Pipeline in parallel

Tags: azure-pipelines

What is the best way and how do you setup Azure Pipelines so that more than 1 can run at the same time?  Right now, in my account it appears that it is only set up to run 1 pipeline after another, not in parallel.  Do I need to setup a new agent pool and assign some of the pipelines to the new agent pool or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is new you it could be caused by [this limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted):

> We have temporarily disabled the free grant of parallel jobs for public projects and for certain private projects in new organizations. However, you can request this grant by submitting [a request](https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request). Existing organizations and projects are not affected. Please note that it takes us 2-3 business days to respond to your free tier requests.

If you want to go into paid solution on ogranization level go to setttings and setup billing:

[image]

Comment: I did make that request.  There should be another solution where I could scale this to handle n number of jobs at the same time.  You can buy anything with money, right?  What is that solution?

Comment: You need to create a billing for this on organization level.